# Show all comments on a post, but show a username only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

On a specific `Users` post, I want to show all comments, but show a given username only once.

I already have a `Post` model associated with all of its `Comments`. The `Comments` are associated with their `Users`. But I can't figure out how to show only a given user's username once. So instead of:

```
User1: "I commented First"
User2: "I commented Second"
User1: "I'm commenting Again!!!!"
User1: "And....Again!"
```

I should have:

```
User1: "I commented First"
       "I'm commenting Again!!!!"
       "And....Again!"
User2: "I commented Second"
```

This code manages to show all the comments on the page.

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if comment.id %>
    <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user %> says: <%= comment.content %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it fails to show a username only once with all of that username's comments.

Currently a:

```
`User` `has_many :comments`, `has_many :posts, through: :comments`
`Post` `has_many :comments`, `has_many :users, through: :comments`
`Comment` `belongs_to :user`, `belongs_to :post`
```

Comment: You can try the answer given below for better explanation.

Comment: Have you really thought this through? What if the comments are a dialog? If you sort them by user instead of chronologically then they may stop making sense.

Comment: @max this is one of the rspec tests I’m trying to get passing. I didn’t write the test

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`group_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by). By specifying `&:user` we tell `group_by` that we want to group by the result of the `user` attribute of every comments, here is **an example**:

```
<% @post.comments.group_by(&:user).each do |user, comments| %>
   #- user variable contains a user record 
   #- comments is an array of comments
   <%= link_to user.username, user %> <%= comments.map(&:content) %> 
<% end %>
```

This example just shows you a way how to do that.

<sub>Actually this way will generate [N+1 problem](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), you should load comments in sub-query</sub>

Comment: I prepared same but you posted it +1

Comment: I did attempt this first and it ended up printing this to the screen:
User 1 says: ["first comment", "second comment"]

Comment: @AustinBurke sorry, I dont get.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and in the browser it showed the comments as an array of comments, rather than as:
User1 says: "first comment"
"second comment"

Comment: That's because I've shown you an example, try change `comments.map(&:content)` to `comments.map(&:content).to_s`.

Comment: I attempted that, but it is still in an array. Sorry I have never used `&:` before, so a little unsure about how to customize it.

Comment: `comments` here is an array, you can use `each` on it, `&:content` it's shortcut for `comments.map { |x| x.content }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = @post.comments.group_by(&:user)
```

users is now a hash that will look like this:

```
{“George Brassens” => [#<Comment id:131 …>, #<Comment id:331 …>], “Billie Holiday” => [#<Comment id:111 …>, #<Comment id:911 …>] }
```

So it can be iterated as comments for the user

```
<%users.each_pair do |user, comments|
  <h1><%= link_to user.username, user %> says:</h1><br>
  <%comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%=comment.body%><br />
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Actually `users` is hash so it can be sorted too

```
<%users.keys.sort.each do |author|
  <h1><%= link_to author.username, author %> says: </h1><br>
  <%users[author].each do |comment|%>
    <%=comment.body%><br />
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```